# Calculo de sumatoria

Tags: c++, dev-c++

```
introducir el código aquí
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

int a,b,c;
int total = 0;

cin>>a;

for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
    cin>>b;
    cin>>c;
}

for(int i=b; i<=c; i++){
    total += i;
    cout<<total<<"\n";
}
    
}
```

En la parte del resultado de total, solo me sale el ultimo resultado correcto, los primeros 2 resultados, me salen diferente a como tiene que salir.

Este es un ejemplo de como debe de dar el resultado.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El primer numero es que se sumaran 3 cadenas:

En este caso la primera cadena es 1 3 ( se sumara desde 1 hasta el 3). El resulatdo de esta cadena es 6.

La segunda cadena es 2 7 ( se sumara desde 2 hasta el 7).
El resulatdo de esta cadena es 27.

La tercera cadena es 5 7 ( se sumara desde el 5 hasta el 7).
El resulatdo de esta cadena es 18.

Comment: Como te comenté en tu otra pregunta. Mínimo, explica de que trata el problema. Cual es el input, que representa 1 3, que esperas como salida. No se trata de adivinar que estás preguntando.

Comment: Listo, ya lo edite. Una disculpa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para tratar cada test tienes que meter el segundo bucle dentro de primero:

```
for(int i=0; i<a; i++){
    cin>>b;
    cin>>c;

    for(int i=b; i<=c; i++){
        total += i;
        cout<<total<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Como tu lo has hecho, pides 3 parejas de valores pero machacas constantemente `b` y `c`, con lo que al final solo te quedas con el último par de valores.

Finalmente, el segundo bucle se ejecuta una única vez ... usando el último par de valores.

Consejo: Intenta dar nombres más representativos a las variables